# initiating a touchend event - jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile for my application.

Is it possible to release a gesture using jQuery Mobile? If a user places fingers and drag the screen - can I release this gesture using JavaScript, even if he leaves his finger on the screen?

For example - is it possible to release touch move after 1000 ms so the event will end, such as `$(this).touchend();` (like I could do `$(this).click();`) ?

**Edit:**
On the other hand, maybe someone has any other idea on how to limit the `touch` / `touchmove` time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this work?

- http://jsfiddle.net/LG9BM/

JS

```
function bindEventTouch(element) {
    element.bind('tap taphold swipe swiperight swipeleft', function(event, ui) {
        console.log('Event: '+event.type); 

        if(event.type == 'taphold') {
            console.log('Was Event taphold?: '+event.type); 
            element.trigger('touchend');
        }
    });

    element.bind('touchend', function(event, ui) {
        console.log('Triggered touchend Event: '+event.type); 
    });
}

$('.displayEvent').each(function(){
    bindEventTouch($(this));
});​
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="display-event-1" class="add-border displayEvent">
            <p>Tap, TapHold (for 1 second), Swipe, SwipeRight or SwipeLeft</p>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="display-event-2" class="add-border displayEvent">
            <p>Tap, TapHold (for 1 second), Swipe, SwipeRight or SwipeLeft</p>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="display-event-3" class="add-border displayEvent">
            <p>Tap, TapHold (for 1 second), Swipe, SwipeRight or SwipeLeft</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.add-border {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    width:100%;   
    text-align:center;
}​
```

Comment: Thanks for the super-detailed explination - I'm a bit new to jsFiddle - I tried to open the URL with my iPhone, but no events fired when I tried to tap those elements, am I doing somthing wrong?

Comment: OK got it :) - not console.log on iPhone. I'll change that to alert... Thanks!

Comment: You can use console http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html

Answer (score 5):

You can trigger any event by calling `$(this).trigger(eventName)`
See the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) on this method.

Your case would be: `$(this).trigger('touchend');`

If you want an event that will fire after 1000ms of a touch, maybe consider the [taphold](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) event from jQM? You can specify the delay by setting `$.event.special.tap.tapholdThreshold`.